# Microsoft Graph API DateTimeZone date format

Tags: android, microsoft-graph-api

Microsoft Graph API uses a `DateTimeZone` class for dates and it has a format similar to `2017-12-21T14:30:00.0000000`.

How do I detect which format this is in order to create `events` from an Android application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DateTime is in the format defined by [ISO 8601](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime).

If you want to parse that to Date then you can use (Java 8 at least):

```
DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;
TemporalAccessor temporalAccessor = timeFormatter.parse("2017-12-21T14:30:00.0000000");

Date date = Date.from(Instant.from(temporalAccessor));
```